# Help using maxFratio() in R (Hartley's test)

Tags: r, variance, heteroscedasticity

I found documentation at:  http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/SuppDists/html/maxFratio.html

I am not sure how really to use this though and am coming up short finding help online.

If anyone has a link or tutorial on this in R please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to know, is that really about R or about the $F_\max$ ?

From what I understand, $F_\max(df,k)$ is the distribution of the maximum ratio between empiric variances computed on k gaussian samples (all estimating the same "true variance" σ²), all with the same degrees of freedom df (= sample size - 1).

As empiric variances follow a (scaled) χ² distribution, you can easily generate $F_\max$ values :

```
k <- 5; N <- 10000; df <- 14
X <- matrix( rchisq(k*N, df=df), ncol=k)
maxv <- apply(X,1,max)
minv <- apply(X,1,min)
```

Plot their histogram:

```
hist(maxv/minv,freq=FALSE,breaks=100)
```

And superimpose the distribution given by `dmaxFratio()`:

```
x <- seq(0,50,by=0.1)
lines(x, dmaxFratio(x, df, k), col="red")
```

Now that we see that this is working, it appears that the first block of code could have been shorcuted by  `rmaxFratio(N, df, k)`.

You can use this in anova to test for homogeneity of variance between $k$ groups
all with $df$ degrees of freedom. To get a $p$-value, compute the ratio `r` of the smallest variance to the highest, the $p$-value is `pmaxFratio(r, df, k, lower.tail=FALSE)`. You can also compare `r` to the quantile `qmaxFratio(0.95, df, k)`.

If you have more specific questions, please... be more specific :)

Comment: r should be the ratio of the largest variance to smallest variance among the groups